# How to access a referenced data with objectId of MongoDB in Flutter?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, flutter-dependencies

> I'm new to Flutter. I used nodejs and MongoDB as Backend API. How do I access DataModel with ObjectId references in Nested Database in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use populate function with find method in mongodb: [Ref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)

Let's assume that there is userDeatils model which is referenced withing user model like this :

```
var user = new Schema({
name:String,
userdetails:{
type:mongoose.types.ObjectId,
ref:'userDetails'
}
});
```

Then You can Find data using Query like :

```
db.user.find({name:"Ram"}).populate('userdetails')
```

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]